# New struts car pulls to the right

Tags: toyota, camry, alignment, struts

I replaced both front struts on my 2008 camry the car did not pull b4 this but now does . I checked the tire pressure and it was fine I then took it for an alignment and all 4 are within spec no adjustments needed .I then tried swapping out both front tires for each other and that didn’t work I’m 99.9 percent sure the brakes are not dragging the only thing I can think of is a possible defective strut?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Or get a second opinion on the alignment ...

Comment: Did you finally tighten all the suspension bolts with the weight on the ground?

Comment: Could be a radio pull due to tire wear. If the old struts caused different wear patterns on each tire they could be causing the car to drift right or left. You didn't specify whether or not it pulled the other direction or not when you switched tires around. My guess is that this probably isn't the case but I'd inspect the tires to check for differing wear on the front. Another thing would be to bring the rears forward and test again.

Comment: Another thought here, the alignment shop may say no adjustment necessary because the issues are in places that aren't adjustable. If you have/saw the actual measurements from before and after you can check there. Just another idea for you. Best of luck

Comment: Gabe I’m going to try the tears on the front this weekend there is no obvious wear the tires are like new and when I swapped the fronts it still pulled to the right which is the initial problem

Comment: if you take a look at this video from timestamp 21.20 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4Lcgp4gBXI i just wonder if this adjustment has been done correctly after you changed the struts.

Answer (score 1):

Get another alignment check.
Some places simply check the toe and call it a day.
To check the caster you *MUST* turn the steering wheel so the tires pivot roughly 30degrees left and right.  I see plenty of shops put the car on the lift, hit a couple of buttons and then printout the sheet.  It is not physically possible to measure caster that way (its why I don't got to NTB anymore).
Watch them do it.  Make sure they turn the wheel.
I don't have any strut cars anymore, but when I did, there is no way to get the alignment 'perfect' by chance.  Could be your car is different, just sound fishy.

Comment: I’m very confident the brakes are not dragging as mentioned I swapped the front 2 tires and the car still pulled to the right I’m kinda stuck

Answer (score 1):

bad strut mounts on new struts can occur. this can cause a pull and
has nothing to do with brakes. pull changes with bumps and whether
turning right or left. can also happen as with used or aged struts.
Personal experience identified by Automotive Shop.

Good Luck.......

Answer (score -1):

Defective strut would not cause a pull. The strut doesn't support the weight of the vehicle, the spring does that. The strut only dampens spring oscillations. If the alignment is good, then it's either tires or brakes.

Comment: The shock absorber dampens the oscillations...

Comment: Also by my vocabulary the strut is the coil spring, damper, and associated mounts - the assembly.

Comment: A strut is just the shock.  A strut assembly consists of the strut, strut mount, coil spring, boot and spring cushion.

Comment: Just looked it up and strut seems to just means a structural shock absorber so I stand corrected. Either way though the OP saying strut might mean strut assembly though I'll defer to the OP for that info.

Comment: Is it at all possible it would pull if one doing is tightened down more than the other?

Comment: Any time struts or shocks are replaced, you should have your alignment checked.  Caster, camber, and toe should be checked to see whether they're in spec or not.